# best practice for nesting promises in succession

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I currently have a few functions that return promises such as the below:

```
function action_one(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)->{
        ...
    });
}
```

I want to be able to wait on one before doing the next promise without nesting them. I had searched for some solutions, one being PromiseAll() but it does not seem to do it in order. Another solution was to do the following:

```
   promise.then(result =>{
       action
   }.then(result =>{
       action
   }.then(result =>{
       action
   }.then(result =>{
       action
   }.then(result =>{ etc.
```

which I'm not sure works for my issue but it doesn't seem compactable.

what would be best practice in this situation?

Edit:

I'm not sure how to use the .then chain with multiple promises such as:

```
promise.then(result =>{
       action
   }promise.then(result =>{
       action
   }promise.then(result =>{
       action
   }promise.then(result =>{
       action
   }promise.then(result =>{ etc.
```

It does not yield the result I expect

Comment: How about using async/await so you will have synchronous function

Comment: What's wrong with the `then` chain?

Comment: "*which I'm not sure works for my issue*" - please try it. Then post your real code if you need help/advise on it, not the sample with missing parenthesis. "*but it doesn't seem compactable.*" - not sure what you mean there?

Comment: i've added a bit more information to my question. 

i'm not sure how the .then chain can work with multiple different promises

Comment: what does *doesn't seem compactable.* mean? Promises essentially exist so you can chain the then without nesting. You other option (if you can use it) would be async/await. But this question really isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 1

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // (*)
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2), 1000);
  });

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 2

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2), 1000);
  });

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 4

});
```

I needed to return the promise to chain them which is why it was not working.
Source: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining